# How to run two inbound adapters in mutually exclusive fashion

Tags: spring-integration

[image]I have two `inbound-channel-adapter` in my SI application, both of them feeding same output channel, which is than subsequently processed through a series of other SI components.

First adapter runs every 10 minute while the second one is event based and can run anytime (in fact polls every 100 msec for new events).

I would like both of these adapters to run one at a time. So for example, if the first one is running and its output is being processed the second adapter should wait for the first adapter (hence its transaction) to complete. Is there any built in mechanism in SI that i can use to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a task executor on the `<poller/>`s, with a single thread (e.g. a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` with a pool size of 1), and a `CallerBlocksPolicy` in its `rejectedExecutionHandler` and a queue size of 1.

A queue size of 0 with the default ABORT policy should work too.

Comment: Actually, a queue size of 0 and ABORT policy should be ok too.

Comment: Will not introducing a queue means the transaction will no longer cover rest of processing? I will need to play with this though.

Comment: If there's no room in the queue and the ABORT policy is in place, the task scheduler will simply fail to launch the poll so a transaction won't even be started. If the thread is available then all will work as before. For the caller blocks policy to work, the queue has to have at least one slot so you will always have a pending poll in the queue, even though the second one will block.

Comment: It has not worked for me the way I want. Introducing a common queue to capture adapter output with size 1, commits the transaction started by inbound-channel-adapter when the message is delivered in size 1 queue, when I want it to commit only when the complete processing is successful, else rollback. 
Added a picture above to explain what I am looking, I need when adapter 1 is working, adapter 2 should not. Any thoughts please? Thank you

Comment: What is a "Direct Queue"? There's no such thing in the framework. I said use a task executor with one thread.

Comment: I meant a Direct Channel, how do i associate the two adapters to a task executor with one thread? I can create a channel in between  and do dispatcher task-executor="taskExecutor" but that is making the transaction to commit as i said.

Comment: No; the common single-threaded `task-executor` needs to be configured on the `<poller/>`.